# Overwrite a nested function or attach new functionality

Tags: javascript

I am using an external JavaScript library which must remain unchanged. I need functionality to be kicked off whenever a particular function has been called / completed.

Previously I would have overridden the function in question and added my code to the end. However the latest version of this external library has the function nested within a funcdtion.

Is there a way in which I can override / attach the new functionality to the 3rd party function?

```
function View() {}

window.View = View;

View.FunctionINeedToChange = View_FunctionINeedToChange;
function View_FunctionINeedToChange(a) {
    // Code
    }
}
// I need my code to execute here
```

The "View_FunctionINeedToChange" is called internally within the 3rd party script, however the only thing that I can override is "View.FunctionINeedToChange", so my changes are making no difference.

Comment: How is that function called?

Comment: *"I can override is "View.FunctionINeedToChange"*. So what is the problem if you *can* do it, this is exactly what you need.

Comment: There's no closure in the code you posted (but a stray closing brace). Can you add it, please?

Comment: Hi @dfsq, The View.FunctionINeedToChange is not actually called anywhere within the 3rd party script, only View_FunctionINeedToChange is called.

Comment: I think you are mis-using the term "closure" to refer to a nested function. The two concepts are related, but distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've defined a prototypical object, you can add functions to the instance with `Object.defineProperty`.

```
view = new View()
Object.defineProperty(view, 'FunctionINeedToChange', {
    value: function (input, param, etc) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Or, you can attach your function to the prototype of `View`.

```
View.prototype.FunctionINeedToChange = function (input, param, etc) {
    // your code here
};
```

The difference being the first example will only change the single instance of `view` to use your functionality, whereas the second example will change *all* instances created (even ones that were created in the past!).

However, all of this will mean nothing if your third party code executes its own code before seeing the changes you've added to `View`, or if it uses a lexically scoped definition of it (which is likely the case).

I think you're better off not trying to alter third party code by monkey patching its internal object definitions, but instead relied on constructing your own instances and altering them for your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are outside the closure, you cannot override the function that is inside the closure. Also adding custom logic in that particular library is not a good thing to do because when you upgrade it to a newer version you will lose your custom work.